android studio sign for play store
I wonder if anyone can help with generating an upload key for the play store?
I have a .aab built is powerapps, which handles the wrap process, generating an .aab and .apk file.
I can install the app on my device manually by opening the file - this works ok.
From what I understand, I need to click Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK in android studio. I dont see that option, but presume I need to open the AAB first?
the issue is the file doesnt seem to open, my clean android studio install looks like this
When I open the AAB, nothing seems to happen?
(https://i.sstatic.net/261ClmPM.png)
to code sign the app.
I was expecting a certificate to be generated

Does this help you?
